# BDF2: How to Implement

Tags: numerical-methods

While I had a course a couple years ago concerning the implementation of linear time marching methods, I'm pretty rusty and am getting stumped here.  I'm attempting to implement the BDF2 time marching method in order to convect Lagrangian points in space and time.  What I have are the locations of these points and the velocities at which the points need to be convected (which is really just linear advection), but the underlying methodology that governs the velocity at each point is said to be unstable for explicit TMMs and BDF2 was specifically recommended as a higher order method to ensure stability after the first time step.

So, the equation that I'm trying to integrate (where *r* is a position vector, *t* is time, and *V* is velocity):

$$
\frac{\delta \vec{r}}{\delta t}=\vec{V}
$$

The RHS of this expression is highly nonlinear, although it is analytical and I have discrete values of *V* readily available.

So, the query: how do I implement a time marching method (specifically BDF2) for this problem?  The formulation that I've found is as follows (where *n* denotes the time step level):
$$
\vec{r}_{n+1}=\frac{4}{3}\vec{r}_n-\frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}(\Delta t)\frac{\delta \vec{r}_{n+1}}{\delta t}
$$

The kicker for me is discretizing the last term (i.e., the derivative of *r* with respect to *t*).  My thought is that I could just make a 2nd order Taylor approximation for the derivative using a predicted value the future time step (using the Euler explicit method) and then the actual values at present and prior time steps and use that.  Would that be a correct methodology?

Comment: Unclear what is meant by the last term. Perhaps write down the original PDE.

Comment: Still unclear what the PDE is. Also, I assume you mean to use ``\partial`` instead of ``\delta`` in your LaTeX. Perhaps you should cite the textbook/source you are using. Might be easier.

Comment: Hmm...OK -- perhaps I've been mistaking something and this is a better explanation.  I'm attempting to integrate the first expression in time, which I cannot do explicitly due to the mentioned instability issues that are caused by discrete jumps in the velocity field.  Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Can you be explicit about what $V$ is? What is it a function of? Same with $r$. Use my notation as a guide.

Comment: V...is tricky.  Short answer: to sample V, I have to draw up a dense coefficient matrix [A] based on the geometry of a model, solve the resulting linear system Ax=b, and then multiple the vector x with a second dense coefficient matrix [C] also derived from geometry.  In short, it is analytic, and varies in time and space.

r is a little more straightforward.  It's a position vector that only depends on the points of interest.  It varies in time and space.

Does that answer your query?  I'm not sure how to express that mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. General framework

I assume your PDE is of the form
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}(t,x)=f(t,x,\mathcal{D}r(t,x))
$$
where 
$$
\mathcal{D}r=(r,Dr,D^{2}r)
$$
and $Dr$ is the gradient of $r$ and $D^{2}r$ is the Hessian of $r$. Then, [BDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_differentiation_formula) is just
$$
r_{i}^{n+1}-\frac{4}{3}r_{i}^{n}+\frac{1}{3}r_{i}^{n}=\frac{2}{3}f(t^{n+1},x_{i},(\mathcal{D}_{h}r^{n+1})_{i})h.\tag{*}
$$
In the above, $h=\Delta t$ is the timestep size and
$$
(\mathcal{D}_{h}r^{n+1})_{i}=(r_{i}^{n+1},(D_{h}r^{n+1})_{i},(D_{h}^{2}r^{n+1})_{i})
$$
where $D_{h}^{p}$ is the matrix containing the stencil for the $p$-th derivative. (*) is a nonlinear equation in $$\vec{r}^{n+1}=(r_{1}^{n+1},\ldots,r_{M}^{n+1})$$ and hence must be solved iteratively (e.g., by Newton's method).

**Remark**: *While I have only included up to second-order derivatives, you can add more*.

### 2. Concrete Example

Consider the PDE
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}(t,x)=\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}(t,x)
$$
This is just a special case of the PDE in Section 1 (i.e., take $f(t,x,\mathcal{D}r(t,x))=\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}(t,x)$). In this case, BDF2 looks like
$$
r_{i}^{n+1}-\frac{4}{3}r_{i}^{n}+\frac{1}{3}r_{i}^{n}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{r^{n+1}_{i-1}-2r^{n+1}_i+r^{n+1}_{i+1}}{(\Delta x)^2}h
$$
where we have used a central difference to discretize the second derivative.

Comment: Could you clarify this for me, please?  What does (*) refer to?  Also, the bit that I'm stuck on, as I noted in my edited question, is what exactly that f(t,x,Dr(t,x)) term refers to...I thought it was just the derivative of r with respect to time, but that's apparently not the case.  Could you please explain?  Pure math is not my forte and I'm having difficulty understanding.

Comment: (\*) is just the equation labelled (\*) (look closely at the right-hand side). $f$ is *any* nonlinear function.

Comment: @Marius: I added a concrete example

Comment: The example helps a lot!  Thanks.  So that makes sense now.  But I'm still trying to work out the application to my problem -- I just updated the question again.